# Path to shell script in aliases with ./

Tags: bash, scripts, execute-command

I'm trying to make an alias for my shell script which is saved in `~/Dokumente/music.sh`

Therefore, I added following line to `~/.bash_aliases`:

> alias music='.//home/robin/Dokumente/music.sh'

After saving, I executed `source ~/.bash_aliases`.

I think the alias itself is working fine, but ./ doesn't find the file. Why? I've tried multiple things (e.g. `~/Dokumente/music.sh`) but nothing works.

I can execute the script when I type `./music.sh` within the containing folder. That shouldn't be the point…

I want the script being executable from any direction with this user.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `./` generally stands for current directory, why do you want to use it in your alias? `./home/...` basically refers to a directory called `home` within your current directory, not `/home`

Comment: `~/Dokumente/music.sh` should worked (try after opening new terminal or new tab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
alias music='/home/robin/Dokumente/music.sh'
```

the `./` part usually denotes current directory, so a relative path.